# why am I getting empty <option> elements in my <select multiple> element

Tags: dart, dart-webui

In this code, I get an empty `<option>` element at the top of the `select` element box. 
I don't have a blank item in the Map that it's bound to. Is this how `template repeat` works for ? Or am I missing something obvious? Or is it a bug?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="multiselect.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Multiselect</h1>

    What books have you read? Choose all that apply.<br>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <template if='!books.isEmpty'>

        <!-- Why am I getting an empty one? -->
        <select multiple
                on-change="changeselected($event)"
                id="bookselector">
            <option template repeat="key in books.keys" value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
        </select>

        <p>You chose:</p>
        <ul>
           <li template repeat='selected in booksselected'>{{selected}}</li>
        </ul>
      </template>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart">
      import 'dart:html';
      import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

      int selectedIndex = 1;
      final Map<String, bool> books = toObservable(
          { 'The Cat in the Hat': true, 'War and Peace': false,
            'Pride and Prejudice': true, 'On the Road': true,
            'The Hunger Games': true, 'The Java Tutorial':  false,
            'The Joy of Cooking': false, 'Goodnight Moon': true }
      );

      void main() {
      }

      List<String> get booksselected {
        // Return the keys of the selected items.
        return books.keys.where((c) => books[c]).toList();
      }

      void changeselected(Event e) {
        // Get the selected elements.
        List<OptionElement> options = (query('#bookselector') as SelectElement).selectedOptions;
        // Set everything to false temporarily.
        books.forEach((k, v) => books[k] = false);
        // Set true for selected items.
        options.forEach((e) => books[e.value] = true);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Repeat? Why don't you use iterate?

Comment: Ok, forget it, take a look at this issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/472 and this discussion https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/web-ui/UZ4b695Hzi4

Have you tried to use template repeat inside select tag instead option?